# How to call product url in email generated by Magento

Tags: magento

I have an email that is being generated from within magento that shows what a customer has bought. (Based on New Order Template).

Is it possible to make the item listed a link so it can be clicked and directly go to the item on my website. It sounds so simple, but can't find any info how to do this within magento.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

In design, you have an email folder. Just override email/order/items/order/default.phtml and email/order/items.phtml if you want a new column. Good luck ! :) If you want more details, ask me and I`ll help you .

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but that's not what I was asking.

I want the product that is bought and listed in the new order email sent to the customer to have an active link back to the item on my website. So that the customer can view the product again on my website.

Hope that's clearer, so is it possible to have an active link of a product in a sent email?

Comment: Hi Ana Maria, thanks for that, I'm new to magento, where in the new order email template would I put this code?

Comment: In email/order/items.phtml , $product = $item->getProduct(); $url = $product->getProductUrl();